# How to align ImageView to the right side of the LinearLayout Programmatically android

Tags: android

i want to align an ImageView to the right side of the LinearLayout Programmatically.How can i do this.

Comment: LinearLayout does not support this. You could wrap your ImageView with a RelativeLayout inside your LinearLayout.

Answer (score 24):

You don't. That is not what a linear layout does. Use a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) instead.

XML

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello, World!"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Programmatically

```
public void makeView(Context context) {
    RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(context);
    TextView tv = new TextView(context);
    tv.setText("Hello, World");

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
            (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

    rl.addView(tv, lp);
}
```

Comment: ok how can i add programmatically a TextView to RelativeLayout with Right alignment.

Comment: I dont want to use an XML layout.I want to display programmatically because the data is dynamic.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
ImageView view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
```

But you should use `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout`.